Why does Lean 4 not execute the given code?
I have function
def KexpVV(key: Array UInt8) (blen: Nat) (rkey: Array UInt8) (f: IO.FS.Stream) : IO (Array UInt8) := do
   f.putStr "Some debug text\n"
   ...

which was used like this
def ShortTestKExp (f: IO.FS.Stream) (src: Option IO.FS.Stream) : (IO Unit) := do
    -- let mut key := mkArray (α := UInt8) MAXKEYLEN 0
    let rkey := mkArray (α := UInt8) ((RNDS MAXKEYLEN) * MAXBLOCKLEN) 0
    let key: IO ByteArray :=
      match src with
      | some src  => src.read (USize.ofNat MAXKEYLEN)
      | none      => random_arr MAXKEYLEN

    f.putStr s!"\nKey expansion for {(MAXKEYLEN * 8)} bit key and {MAXBLOCKLEN * 8} bit block:\n"
    let key := (← key).data
    _ := KexpVV key MAXBLOCKLEN rkey f
    f.putStr "\n"

and when I run code, it prints only
Key expansion for 128 bit key and 128 bit block:



without printing anything from KexpVV. What should I do?

There is a similar question on SO for the same issue in Haskell. The syntax is different, of course, but maybe the answers there can help explain the difference between <- and :=.

Thank you, it was really helpful

You're getting hit by the difference between := and ←. Consider the following code, mimicking what you're trying to do:
def cow (msg : String) (f: IO.FS.Stream) : IO Int := do
  f.putStrLn msg
  return 42

def main (_ : List String) : IO Unit := do
  let out ← IO.getStdout.toIO
  let a := cow "this will NOT print" out
  let b ← cow "this will print" out

The program prints:
% lean --run LeanScratch.lean
this will print

In the function main, the type of a is IO Int and the type of b is Int. That's because only ← actually runs the monadic code in the IO monad, whereas := just constructs a computation (without running it).
In your program, just replace the line _ := KexpVV key MAXBLOCKLEN rkey f (which is trying to modify an anonymous variable?) with KexpVV key MAXBLOCKLEN rkey f and it'll work. (That is, delete _ :=.)
If you'd like further explanation of the difference between the two, please say so.

Honestly I did try
_ := KexpVV key MAXBLOCKLEN rkey f

and
KexpVV key MAXBLOCKLEN rkey f

and even (that's silly, but hey)
let someunusedvar := _ := KexpVV key MAXBLOCKLEN rkey f

and results was the same.

Okay let dummy ← KexpVV key MAXBLOCKLEN rkey f was working for me, so I think gist of your advice is what I really need.

It turns out, that since result of KexpVV was unused, Lean4 does not execute it, so I have to use discard like that
discard <| KexpVV key MAXBLOCKLEN rkey f


Your explanation is incorrect in the sense that you are fixing the problem "by accident". The real problem is the difference between := and ←.
